# AWS EKS ReadWriteMany QlikSense instsallation

Tags: kubernetes, qliksense, amazon-eks

I am currently installing QlikSense on Kubernetes. In order to work with Qlik the Kubernetes Cluster needs to have a readwritemany storage class.

How do I configure a readwritemany storage class in EKS with kubectl?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon AWS supports Elastic File System (EFS) as a highly scalable NFS service basically. By installing their new CSI driver in your EKS cluster, this allows a ReadWriteMany storage class. This should satisfy your requirements. You can read more about installing that [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html).

Note however that EFS performance will not be great. It depends on how the software will want to use it. For example, hosting a database on EFS is not recommended and will probably be too slow. However, hosting shared files on EFS with moderate load and no stringent latency requirements can work well enough!

I am the developer behind [airkube.io](https://airkube.io/), which is a managed EKS hosting that runs on AWS spot instances. We tested and had good luck with [openebs](https://openebs.io/). This is a good option if you need fairly high performance RWX, you can read more about that option [here](https://docs.openebs.io/docs/next/rwm.html). The opebebs solution might bring slight complexity though especially if you don't have a dedicated SRE person, or use a managed EKS solution. Another possibly simpler solution, is to use [NFS provisioner](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nfs-server-provisioner). This deploys an NFS server and dynamically creates PVs as EKS users deploy PVCs.

Hope that was helpful! Don't hesitate to ping me for more details or hands-on help! Regards